# Include paramerised URL in email body of a mailto link

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I have a Javascript variable `fullurl` which is a url of the form `http://example.com/page.php?id=123`

I'd like to create a mailto link with this URL in the body

`html += '<a href="mailto:&subject=Test&body=' + fullurl  +'">Click here</a> to email this link';`

The result is an email with the body of just `http://example.com/page.php` so I imagine it is the ? in the URL throwing it off, as it interprets it as the end of the body= part of mailto

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use encodeURIComponent.

`fullurl = encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/page.php?id=123")`

Comment: still doesnt work - it can print the URL perfectly fine on the page itself but when I try to include it in mailto body it removes the ?id=123

Comment: Another reason could have been that you used the & parameter at the start, since the first parameter should be specified with an ?. This code worked for me: `<body><script>fullurl = encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/page.php?id=123"); document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="mailto:?subject=Test&body=' + fullurl  +'">Click here</a> to email this link';</script></body>`